# RSpec: How to test call of another classes method inside of a method?

Tags: ruby, rspec

So I have some classes in a gem and I'm struggling to test specific lines in my code. The class `Foo` has two attributes, both of which are instances of classes `User` and `Client`. How can I test that `Foo.get_events(date)` calls the method `Client.get_events(user, date)`?

```
class Foo
  attr_reader(:user, :client)

  def get_events(date)
    client.get_events(user[:id], date)
  end
end
```

```
class Client
  def get_events
    # Makes API call here
  end
end
```

I already have mocked requests for `Client.get_events` and that method is successfully tested, but I can't figure out how to test that `Foo.get_events` calls that method.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
describe 'Foo#get_event' do
  let(:client) { instance_double(Client) }
  let(:user) { { id: 'user_id' } } 
  let(:date) { Date.today }

  subject(:foo) { Foo.new(user, client) } 

  before { allow(client).to receive(:get_events).and_return(true) }
  
  it "delegates to the client's method" do
    foo.get_event(date)

    expect(client)
      .to have_recieved(:get_events)
      .with('user_id', date)
      .once
  end
end
```

I assumed that `user` is a hash because of the `user[:id]` call. The instance of `Foo` might need to be initialized differently to set `user` and `client` but you didn't share what your `initialize` method looks like.

Furthermore, you will notice that your test will fail immediately because you pass two arguments to `client.get_events(user[:id], date)`, but the method definition in `Client` doesn't accept any arguments. It probably has to change to something like this:

```
class Client
  def get_events(user_id, date)
    # Makes API call here
  end
end
```